# How to pass the keyboard key strokes in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I wish to pass the keyboard key strokes inside the shell script

Eg:

```
shift+~
ctrl+l
```

Eg situation:

in the script , at a place i need to execute the `shift+~`  key

I have installed xdotool package and checked it reports :

```
sound@QuadPC:~$   xdotool key shift+~
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

also used,

```
soundar@QuadPC:~$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 &&  xdotool key shift+~
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyError: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

what is the way to pass the keystrokes keys inside the shell script

Comment: How and where do you need to "pass" these? to a `Popen()` process or? A `try` catch statement?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run an X client program (`xdotool`) without an X11 server.  If you do have a graphical display, what is the value of `DISPLAY` in an XTerm running on that graphical display?

Comment: without `xdotool` is it possible to do the same? either in python or shell script

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `xdotool`? And again, what are you trying to pass `shift+~` in to? Just your script as an argument sounds arbitrary.. So I'm guessing you're trying to catch this? Is that it? You just want to catch for instance `Ctrl+C`? if so `import signal` is the way to go here.

Comment: I just need to pass the keyboard keystroke inside the shell script/python script.    after some command get executed, i need to execute shift+~ in the script

Comment: The script doesn't know what `shift+~` is. That kind of information is processed and transformed long before it reaches the script.

Comment: Can you give me an idea how to transform before it reaches script

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you are *actually* trying to accomplish?  Most programs don't have direct access to the keyboard, they are behind multiple layers of I/O handling and receive just text, not keystrokes.  Is there a particular system call you are trying to interact with?

Comment: I need to use the `shift+~` in a script. so that it will do the process of `shift+~` in the place where i used it in the script